# compare two objects with codeModel

Tags: java, sun-codemodel

I have the following code but I'm trying to not use the `direct()` method.

```
JExpression jx = JExpr.direct("java.lang.Thread.currentThread() == android.os.Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()");
```

I have tried finding documentation on using `_if()` I was able to get a couple of simple ones to work, but I don't know how to get it to generate something like that without using direct().  Does anyone know how to do this or know a good place that shows some examples?  I've tried mining through the javadocs but haven't found anything good.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed reply,

While generating the code you need have reference on the classes, such as

```
    java.lang.Thread
    android.os.Looper

JCodeModel programContext = new JCodeModel();

JExpression ifConditionExpression = JExpr.(programContext.ref(java.lang.Thread).staticInvoke("currentThread").eq(programContext.ref(android.os.Looper).staticInvoke("getMainLooper").invoke("getThread")))
```

Now use this expression as if() expression.

Hope you it would solve this problem.